# The Translation of an SQL query to LinQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Due to wierd request from a Customer, I have managed to figure out how to implement it
using SQL query, but I couldn't translate it into LinQ.

```
 SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM table1 where attribute1 like 'value1'),
        (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 where attribute2 like 'value2')
```

What the translation of the query to LinQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just supply a predicate to the `Count()` function

```
var result = new { 
            Count1 = table1.Count(r => r.attribute1.Contains("value1")), 
            Count2 = table2.Count(r => r.attribute2.Contains("value2")) 
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count1 = (from i in table1 where SqlMethods.Like(i.attribute1, "value1") select i).Count();
var count2 = (from i in table2 where SqlMethods.Like(i.attribute2, "value2") select i).Count();
```

Comment: Thanku, it worked for me except for sql Methods, could you please tell me how to substitute the Sql Methods?